# Linq+Reflection to get elements from a list by a field name and a condition

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have for example this class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

I need to search in a List all elements that satisfy a condition,
for ex.   Name == '%th'

```
//Field name in this example can be:  "Id" , "Name" , "Age" ,"Birthdate"
List<SomeClass> Function(string fieldName, string searchedInfo)
{
    return list.Select(x => (fieldObtainedUsingReflection).Value.ToString().Contains(searchedInfo)).ToList();
}
```

I know that I can do something like that:

```
    switch(fieldName)
    {
      case "Id" : 
                 return list.Select(x=>x.Id.ToString().Contains(searchedInfo)).ToList(); 
      case "Name" :
                 return list.Select(x => x.Name.Contains(searchedInfo)).ToList();
     //.....

    }
```

But I wondered if there is another, more generic implementation.

It's possible to do that using LINQ and Reflection?

If it's possible, what is the time cost if the list has in avg. 30k elements?

Thank you

Comment: `list.Select(x => x.GetType().GetMember(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue().ToString()...)`
Of course, it's not the best solution... Instead of reflection you can use `Expressions`

Comment: Is `Select` what you're needing to use here, or is `Where`?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria It did not work for me because I'm trying to get the data from the Db , and the reflection code cannot be translated in a Sql query. It was my fault that I forgot to say about it.

Comment: @GheorgheVolosenco, oh, if so I suggest you to close this question or edit it append the info about Db) Instead of reflection you can use `Expressions` as part of sql query. You can ask how to do this with `Expressions` or just find a several examples on the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in a comment you can use an Expression, like this:

```
 public static List<SomeClass> SearchBy(this IEnumerable<SomeClass> items, Expression<Func<SomeClass, bool>> predicate)
        {
           return items.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
```

Then you can used like this:

```
        var list = new List<SomeClass>();

        var result= list.SearchBy(x => x.Name.Contains("x"));
```